# Building an array in a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a Python program that imports 1000s of data point in blocks of 10 points at a time.  From each block of 10 data points a maximum for that set is found, then the program loops to the next 10 data points and continues.  All of this works fine, I just need to build an array to hold my maximum data point that are created once per loop, so I can plot it them later.  How can I create this array within the loop, here is what I have:

```
for count in range(self.files/self.block_length):
    RSS = scipy.fromfile(self.hfile2, dtype=self.datatype, count=self.block_length)
    MaxRSS = np.max(RSS)#Takes the greatest value in the array of size defined by block_length
```

Here MaxRSS works great to save to file or print to screen, as the program loops; however, at the end of the loop it only holds the last value and I need something to hold all of the Max values found

Comment: This could be done with a list comprehension, but really you should be using a numpy array as @unutbu says.  `[scipy.fromfile(self.hfile2, dtype=self.datatype, count=self.block_length).max() for count in range(self.files/self.block_length)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will answer what you want... Assuming your `for` loop breaks the 1000s of points correctly into chunks of 10 (which I don't see in the example), to create an array within an array, you need to make `MaxRSS` a list and then append things to it:

```
MaxRSS = []
for count in range(self.files/self.block_length):
    RSS = scipy.fromfile(self.hfile2, dtype=self.datatype, count=self.block_length)
    MaxRSS.append(np.max(RSS))
```

**EDIT:**

This is not Numpy, but maybe will help:

```
import random

data = []
for _ in range(100):
    data.append(random.randint(1, 100))
# Ok, a is populated with 100 integers. 

# Grab chunks of 10 "points"
chunks=[data[x:x+10] for x in xrange(0, len(data), 10)]

# Initialization for the example done. Now, to your max list:
maxes = []
for chunk in chunks:
    maxes.append(max(chunk))
    print "The max number in chunk %s was: %s" % (chunk, maxes[-1])
print maxes #prints out the 10 max values of the 10 arrays of 10 numbers
```

Comment: sounds close, but I get this error:  AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @eltel2910, that's because MaxRSS is still not a list (but a `numpy.float32`). Did you initialize it to [] (or to a Numpy array, maybe?)

Comment: I added RSS_result = [] and changed to RSS_result.append(MaxRSS).  This gets rid of the error, but when I do print RSS_result after the loop I only get the last value

Comment: @eltel2910 did you add the initialization `RSS_result = []` **outside** your `for` loop? Because that's how it should be (otherwise, you're gonna be initializing it on every iteration)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping over 10 points at a time, if you have enough memory to read the entire dataset into an array, then you could reshape the array to a 2D array with 10 values per row, and the take the `max` along the rows:

```
In [59]: x = np.arange(50)

In [60]: x.reshape(-1, 10)
Out[60]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])

In [61]: x.reshape(-1, 10).max(axis=1)
Out[61]: array([ 9, 19, 29, 39, 49])
```

Comment: 200k rep o_0 what's the secret?

Comment: Opening the file using numpy.memmap would eliminate the requirement that the file be fully read into memory...